# Реляции в модели `yii`

Tags: php, yii

Здравствуйте, есть реляции в модели `yii`:

```
/models/Category.php
```

---

```
'products'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Products', 'category_id', 'limit'=>'4',  'with'=>array('pics')).
```

/model/Products.php

```
'pics'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ProductsImages', 'products_id'),
```

Таким образом я хочу вывести 4 товара, с ихними расцветками, но запрос выводит 1 товар с цветами, максимум 4 цвета на товар, Как добиться того чего хочу я?

---

**Решение:**

```
'products'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Products', 'category_id', 'limit'=>'4', 'with'=>array('pics'=>array('together'=>false))).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам столкнулся с этой бедой недавно. Дело в том, что у Вас вероятно запрос выполняется с $criteria->together = true, то есть выборка выполняется за 1 запрос (через JOIN). Когда таблицы объединяются в одну, Ваш LIMIT=4 выбирает 4 записи (из уже объежиненной таблицы). Точнее очень странно выбирает. 
У меня было дерево. Нужно было взять 10 "веток" и все их "листья". Выбиралось то не 10 веток, то не все их листья...
Решение: сделать together = false, но учтите, что тогда не сможете искать по связанным полям. Я собирал id веток и потом листья искать WHERE parent_id IN (...) и тут нужные мне связанные условия. Не знаю хорошо ли решил проблему, но пока что работает
Сам буду рад услышать хорошее решение. И как все таки работает LIMIT для JOIN'ов. Потому что у меня при LIMIT=10 выбиралось 15-20 записей.

UPD:

```
...
$products_id = array();
foreach($model->products as $product)
    $products_id[] = $product->id;

$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->addInCondition($products_id);
$product_images = ProductsImages::model()->findAll($criteria);
//$product_images - будет содержать все цвета.
```

Comment: В данном случаи я не использую критерии

$model=Category::model()->findByPk($id); 
ну и дальше обращаюсь к реляции, $model->products

Comment: Странно, что она срабатывает по умолчанию. Обычно делают так:  
  
    $model=Category::model()->with('products')->together()->findByPk($id);  
  
Вроде не должна всегда выбираться с реляцией.  
Сейчас напишу как я делал, но для вашего случая

Comment: Решение уже есть, спасибо за наводку :)